# Is it possible to develop decent plugins using Ruby?

Tags: vimscript

I've been playing around trying to learn VimL and to do so, I'm toying with the Evernote Ruby SDK to do basic stuff. Is there a reference manual where to find a full Ruby bindings guide or something that helps develop Vim plugins using Ruby? or is the `:h ruby` man all there is? I mean, is it worth the effort?

Comment: What are you missing from `help ruby`? It seems fairly comprehensive?

Comment: A way to get an array from the Ruby result to a Vim var. For now I think the only way is the `Vim.set_option` but that would require casting the Array to string but with Vim format

Comment: There is also `Vim::command()`, though that still requires a string.

Comment: The Ruby documentation in `:help ruby` definitely seems anemic compared to the equivalent Python or Lua documentation, though I'm not sure if that's because of poor documentation, or a poor implementation.

Comment: I've done some ruby stuff with vim, we use ruby/rake as task/script lang at work. And as far as my limited experience, it is very similar to python in interaction with vim, most of the python docs are usable for ruby. My main problem with it is that the default vim binary for windows does not have ruby support compiled in, and I dont want to invest the time on win but still want everything to work. And because I also started to make custom stuff for ultisnips, which is python only atm, I decided to rewrite everything I had (only a few source files) in python.

Comment: btw: I can't find the code anymore, but I'm pretty sure I have used `ary.to_json` after a `require 'json'` to get arrays and hashes from ruby into a vimscript variable.